# Effects of annealing on defects in solid

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science

What is the effect of annealing on the defects present in the sample? Does it remove defects in the sample? Is there any chance that due to annealing the point defects present in the sample combine to form a large size void?

Comment: It is better if you ask it on, engineering stack exchange.

Comment: @yuvrajsingh there is a lot of rich physics associated with defects in materials. This question is very much on topic here

Comment: At a given temperature there is a thermodynamically determined equilibrium population of the various point defects. Void nucleation is, like bubble nucleation, also a thermodynamic process.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a fairly broad subject and you don't say what sample you are considering. Based on my experience with barium oxide and barium sulfide single crystals, annealing can remove defects, and it can also create them.

When we first grew the crystals they were cloudy, and with annealing at a high temperature, they became clear.  The annealing increased the mobility of the atoms in the crystal, and they arranged themselves into a more perfect crystal structure, which in the case of these crystals were face-centered-cubic.

Heating the crystals in an atmosphere of barium created defects by adding excess barium and creating oxygen or sulfur vacancies in the crystal structure.  This process turned the crystals blue, but they were still transparent. You can find more information on this process by searching the internet for "color centers".

Annealing these crystals again in vacuum got rid of the vacancies.

Comment: Thank you Bill for your answer. We are using FeCrMnNi for defect study. This material is supposed to have high radiation resistance. At first, we annealed it at 1200 deg C to remove the defects but in later stages, we induce defects in sample knowingly. Now we are again doing annealing at different temperature in increasing order to know the temperature at which these defects start to move. I come to know about a phenomenon called "void swelling", in which these vacancy defects will combine to form a large size void, which is unwanted in the reactor environment.